# How to document class that has same name in another package?

Tags: java, code-documentation

In Java, one can have classes that can share the same name but belong to different packages altogether. However what is the best way to inform the user that this class belongs to a particular package?

Suppose you have the following scenario:

**pkg1/AwesomeClass.java**

```
package pkg1;
public class AwesomeClass {
}
```

**pkg2/AwesomeClass.java**

```
package pkg2;
public class AwesomeClass {
}
```

-----CODE SNIPPET ON MY GITHUB TO EXPLAIN TO USERS/DEVELOPERS------

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new AwesomeClass();
    }
}
```

How would you tell the user that the `AwesomeClass()` being instantiated in the **Main.java** belongs to pkg1 and not pkg2? By using the absolute path or is there a better way?

This happens quite often in Java world as there are some common names used by 3rd party libraries and often create a source of confusion for end-user/developer.

Comment: Write `new pkg1.AwesomeClass()`.  Or write `import pkg1.AwesomeClass` so it's clear what `new AwesomeClass()` means.

Comment: Why not show the imports on the Main.java snippet? (`import pkg1.AwesomeClass`). That would clarify which package class you are referring to. Alternatively, you could include the fully qualified class name (`new pkg1.AwesomeClass();`).

Comment: Hi @NazaretK. that's a good idea!